# SharePoint: How to apply a custmised masterpage to Sharepoint build-in search results page (OSSSearchResults.aspx)

Tags: sharepoint, master-pages

SharePoint: How to apply a customised masterpage to Sharepoint build-in search results page (OSSSearchResults.aspx)

I have apply the sharepoint sites to use my own customised masterpage, but the search result page(OSSSearchResults.aspx) does not pick my masterpage up.

Can anyone help me?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this using a custom developed HTTPModule that assigns the master page.
Here's [one page that described this technique](http://sharepointmagazine.net/technical/development/customizing-application-master-pages-masterpages-and-sharepoint-part-5-of-6).